# while updating a table using Entity Framework I get the error:"Cannot update identity column..."

Tags: mysql, asp.net, entity-framework

Using visual Studio 2012 v.11 update 4
.Net 4.5.5x

I am trying to simply update a table in my db from an Gridview interface and I get the above error.
my field is an integer auto increment identity field but my PK is ID column that is GUID.
The question is why should entityframework try to update a field in DB that is set in its properties as "identity"?

I do not get any error while trying to insert or delete a record on the same table from the same grid view control
tnx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

> 1st: You are accidentally updating the PK. This is possible since your PK is a GUID as you mentioned.
>
> 2nd: EF assumes that it has to create a PK for the record.

The solution for the first scenario is to trace the procedure to see where the PK is created accidentally. In case of the second scenario, use the following on the PK in the `DbContext`:

```
 .ValueGeneratedNever(); // EF Core 
  Example:
  entity.Property(e => e.PK).ValueGeneratedNever();
```

OR

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] EF6
public GUID PK {get; set;}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. :)
1) for your first possibility: I am not trying to update the PK, I am using the GridView control and I doubt it does it since in the error message the column name is the: "..Cannot update identity column [humanID] I am not sure how to check to see where the PK is created? I didnt get it!

Comment: 2) Why EF has to assume that? since my PK is also marked as primary key? {I didnt try this because of other funny errors with the EF I decided to install and use VS2015}